# How to start vimdiff in Vertical mode?

Tags: vimdiff

Size of one file is 200 Mb, while the size of another file is 20 Mb. 
I need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop loading the big file, when no vimdiff mode is enabled although I run:

```
vimdiff <(hexdump -C r328.raw) <(hexdump -C r328_000.raw)
```

so I am here now but I would like to have colours for differences:

[image]

How can you start vimdiff of two files in vertical mode?

Comment: Pressing `^C` will abort whatever Vim is doing, such as applying colours. You probably just need to be more patient...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I would like to apply them now to the content what is there. The point is not to wait since I could put there too 2TB file.

Comment: @Masi try running `:diffupdate`

Comment: The "content that is there" is 2TB of data. Vim always reads the entire file into memory, so editing a 2TB file will not work in Vim unless you have a lot of swap space. Vim also doesn't diff by itself, it uses the extenal `diff` tool and parses the output of that. If you want to have it behave different, you'll have to write your own diffexpr function ([`:help diff-diffexpr`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html#diff%2ddiffexpr))...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker My need is max 2 Gb now.

Comment: @muru `:diffupdate` does not respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use use the `--length` option of hexdump to only load 20Mb of the large file so you don't have to cancel what Vim is doing as @Carpetsmoker mentioned.  Ex:

```
vimdiff <(hexdump -C --length=20000000 big) <(hexdump -C small)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `vim -d` (at least my version, 7.4) will open files in vertical mode, i.e. side by side.  (This is equivalent to using `-O` option.)

To open files in "stacked" mode, i.e. one below another, add `-o` option.

Answer (score 0):

To extend on accepted answer: you can just read exactly same number of bytes from both files:

```
vimdiff <(hexdump -C -n $(stat -c %s small) big) <(hexdump -C small)
```

On Mac OSX, the command will instead be:

```
vimdiff <(hexdump -C -n $(stat -f %z small) big) <(hexdump -C small)
```